# double proxied request - get original ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, cloudflare, x-forwarded-for

I have the following setup:

User makes a request, that goes to cloudflare, that acts as a proxy for the request, and redirects it to an aws network load balancer, that finally routes it to its destination.

There I read it with a node server (is actually a socket made with socket.io), and need to get the original ip from it.

I try to read it like this:

> let ip = socket.request.headers['CF-Connecting-IP'] || socket.request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || socket.request.connection.remoteAddress

Both cf and aws lb set x-forwarded-for.

The problem is that I get the cf ip, instead of the end user ip.

If I remove the cf proxy all is well.

It seems to me that aws lb is overwriting the header. Any idea how to make aws lb not to overwrite, but add to list, or not do anything?

Comment: If you're getting the CF IP it probably means it comes from `x-forwarded-for` or `remoteAddress`. Is `CF-Connecting-IP` header not set at all?

Comment: After dumping the full request found the response. CF-Client-IP is not available, but indeed CF-Connecting-IP is. Also there is another solution with a header from aws, called X-Original-Forwarded-For, that holds the "old" x-forwarded-for. @MaxIvanov you are right indeed, that was one of the solutions. I went with the x-original-forwarded for variant because for some reason socket.io transfers that into the headers list, but doesn't transfer cf-connecting-ip (it also lowercase all headers), so the cf one would've been harder to use.

Comment: Mind `X-Forwarded-For` represents a chain of proxies which participated in delivering the request and it may contain multiple IP addresses (comma-separated), client IP being leftmost in the list.

Comment: @MaxIvanov Indeed that's how it is supposed to be. But in cf + aws setup mentioned above only the last one is sent, not the full chain. No idea why. Triple checked it, it is overwritten somewhere (my guess is in aws lb).